# Images not found in Cordova app from Vue project

Tags: vue.js, cordova

Recently I have installed cordova into a VueJS project and almost everything works fine, but statics files are not found like images and I didnt figure out why.

I read something about relative paths like `../../assets` and I tried to change to `assets/` just to see if works but didnt.

Using scss, images are normally imported with `require(../../assets` so I tried to change all my img src to `:src="require(../../assets)"` but still have no success.

I never had to install cordova in a running project, so I didnt know if I'm missing some config.

Here is my src-cordova/config.js

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
   <widget id="medcof.app.io" version="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MedCofQBank</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <!-- this hook will point your config.xml to the DevServer on Serve -->
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="../node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/serve-config-hook.js" />
    <!-- this hook will point your config.xml to the DevServer on Serve -->
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="../node_modules/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/serve-config-hook.js" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
</widget>
```

Comment: have u tried with @ before asset ?